# Возникло исключение: TypeError (listdir)

Tags: python, list

Код на удаления данных из папок, но, что-то не работает.
Пытался удалить файлы из нескольких папок, но только выдает ошибку. Кто нибудь знает, как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
deleteFolder = ['D:/Main/Python Projects/JBAuto/1 (0)', 'D:/Main/Python Projects/JBAuto/1 (0)']
for filename in os.listdir(deleteFolder):
```

Возникло исключение:

> TypeError
> listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not list. File "D:\Main\Python Projects\JBAuto\main.py", line 2, in < module >
> for filename in os.listdir(deleteFolder):

Comment: передавать папки нужно по одной, а не все в одном списке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так у вас в списке пути (строки), метод `os.listdir` на вход тоже требует путь (сроку), а вы ему сразу целый список пихаете, вот он и не понял

как я понимаю, вам необходимо было сделать так:

```
deleteFolder = ['D:/Main/Python Projects/JBAuto/1 (0)', 'D:/Main/Python Projects/JBAuto/1 (0)']

for path in deleteFolder:
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
```